# AttributeError at /post/106/

Tags: python, django

I want to create a "update post" function for my django post app. But I get an error.

> AttributeError at /post/106/
>
> 'Post' object has no attribute 'slug'

**views.py**

```
def post_update(request, slug):

    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return Http404()

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=post)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request, "updated")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(post.get_absolute_url())

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, "blog/post_edit.html", context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = RichTextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('post:update', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

**post_detail.html**

```
<a href="{{ post.get_update_url }}" class="btn btn-default" role="button">update</a>
```

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/update/$', post_update, name="update"),
```

How can I my mistake?
Thanks.

Comment: Where did you create a slugfield in your `Post` model?

Comment: Your `Post` model doesn't have a "slug" model field indeed, so what do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `SlugField` and then write a `save()` function to create `slug` on the basis of some field and then it should work fine.

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=40)
    text = RichTextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    # Write the save() method
    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        super(Post, self).save()

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('post:update', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Comment: Feel privileged to help you.